# Why does it make sense to describe complex numbers through powers of $e$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm studying in-depth complex numbers but I keep wondering why it makes sense to describe complex numbers through powers of $e$.

Comment: Look at a video by a YouTuber calked 3 blue 1 brown very insightful.

Comment: @Karl Do you have a link?!

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why would it not make sense in the first place?

Comment: WWW.3BLUE1BROWN.COM it is on the menu euler identity video.

Comment: Didn't Euler tell you why? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula

Comment: @Jack That's the entire point of the question.

Comment: [Khan Academy's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mgNtPOgFje0) should be useful.

Comment: Do you mean why can it be done, or why should it be done?

Comment: @juanarroyo Both really.

Comment: On the face of it, it's not clear how you would plug a complex number into $e^x$. However, there is an alternate formula for $e^x$: $$e^x = \sum_0^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$This latter definition makes sense for complex numbers, and it turns out that the sum converges (is finite) no matter what complex number you plug in.

Comment: It's useful sometimes the same way that polar coordinates on the plane are useful. It makes formulas involving circles much simpler. A circle is just a set of points $e^{it}$ for $t\in [0,2\pi)$. Sine and cosine become $$\sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{iz}}{2i}$$ $$\cos(z)=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2i}$$ and are defined on the whole complex plane.

Comment: I think this question would be a lot better if you would show explicit, concrete examples of how people use $e$ to describe complex numbers. That is, show us some complex numbers with $e$ in their descriptions that made you wonder why $e$ was used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Because of the convenience of logarithms and antilogarithms.*

Logarithms were invented to turn multiplications and divisions into additions and subtractions, and to implement arbitrary powers.

This feature carries to the complex numbers, and you can write

$$e^{\log w+\log z}=wz.$$

This creates a close connection to the polar form of the complex numbers, i.e. as vectors characterized by a magnitude ($|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$) and an argument ($\angle z=\arctan y/x$) instead of Cartesian coordinates.

Indeed, the product of two complex number is a complex number having for magnitude the product of the magnitudes, and for argument the sum of the arguments. Then if you form a complex number with the real part equal to the logarithm for the magnitude and the imaginary part equal to the argument, you define a complex logarithm:

$$\log wz=\log|wz|+i\angle wz=\log|w|+\log|z|+i\angle w+i\angle z=\log w+\log z.$$

Conversely, the antilogarithm (i.e. the exponential) is the number such that the logarithm of its module is the real part of the given number, and its argument is the imaginary part:

$$\log\rho=x,\\\theta=y$$ which you can invert with

$$e^{x+iy}=\rho(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta).$$

There is much more to be said on the topic. For now, remember that the exponential/logarithm create interesting connections between Cartesian/polar coordinates and a symbiosis with the trigonometric functions, in such a way that many computations are simplified.

Answer (score 2):

Well when you are working with complex numbers in the polar form, expressing them in exponential forms allows easier multiplication of such complex numbers. Thats one reason.

Answer (score 1):

An exponentiated complex number $a+ib;a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ has the form $e^{a+ib} = e^a e^{ib}$.

With Taylor series expansion of $e^{ib}$ it holds

$e^{ib} = 1+ib-\frac{1}{2!}b^2-\frac{i}{3!}b^3+\frac{1}{4!}b^4+\dots$.

If you order it by real and imaginary part you will obtain elementary trigonometric functions. Therefore exponentials of complex numbers are a very good and elegant tool to handle trigonometric entities.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that we have the following function:

$$f(x)=\frac{\cos(x)+i\sin(x)}{e^{ix}}$$

Differentiating once, assuming $e^{ix}$ can be reasonably defined for differentiation,

$$f'(x)=0$$

Thus, it follows that $f(x)$ is constant.  Since it is trivial that $f(0)=1$, then $f(x)=1$ for all $x$, or

$$e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$$

---

One may also alternatively note that $y=e^x$ is analytic, and thus, by Taylor's theorem,

$$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

Similarly, sine and cosine are analytic, with the following Taylor expansions:

$$\cos(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{(2k)!};\quad\sin(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$

Simply by adding, Euler noticed that

$$e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$$

Comment: [Khan Academy's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mgNtPOgFje0) should be useful.